# How to programatically determine if an Android application is obfuscated?

Tags: android

I have and Android app where various people test both development builds and release builds. The development builds are not obfuscated and I would like to be able to programatically determine at runtime if the application has been obfuscated or not.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one idea: add a class to your code base that is not used at all. Proguard will obfuscate and/or remove it. So, loading it via reflection in the app ought to cause `ClassNotFoundException` if it's been run through ProGuard.

Comment: In my mind I have seriously attempted to find the flaw in this attempt... I just cannot do it. This does not happen often... excellent answer sir! lol

Comment: That's correct -- it's smart about finding class names loaded by reflection, but can be defeated if you're really trying to. I think, for example, building the name with steps like `name = "com."; name += "mypackage."; ...` will mean it doesn't find the reference.

Answer (score 1):

As @Sean proposed use a class which has no (external) dependencies.

But beware, ProGuard can detect the use of reflection, so you must somehow load class from string name, by not using a string literal (text resource maybe?): http://proguard.sourceforge.net/index.html#/FAQ.html%23forname

Comment: That is correct because ProGuard ignores the R files. That was the method I was thinking of thus my earlier comment lol

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean? Hard code the unused class name in the strings resource file?

Comment: Yes. Or use any other dynamic way generating a String.

Answer (score 0):

Select a class which is always renamed by Proguard after obfuscation. Its name is `ExampleClass.java` in the code below. Check its name in runtime with the following line:

```
ExampleClass.java
...     
public static final boolean OBFUSCATED = !ExampleClass.class.toString().contains("ExampleClass");
```

That's all. No helper class or method is required and works without causing exceptions.